# Scroll not working for calculated height

Tags: css

```
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

This CSS works fine but if I change the height to a calculated height,

```
height: calc(100% - 100px);
```

the overflow goes hidden and not scrolling or auto.

Any better idea?

Answer (score 2):

Add a .menucontainer around your menu and use the following

```
.menucontainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    position: fixed;
}
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: static;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```